# Magento 1.9.1.0 - Can't find sign in (log in) text in language files

Tags: magento, translation

I am translating Magento 1.9.1.0 but am not able to find the log in text in the language files located at app/locale/nl_NL

Same goes for "Zip/Postal code" I have used Notepad++ to do a search on all files, but no hits.

Has this something to do with the translation I downloaded or is there any other way to change this text?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you folder app/locale/nl_NL in any file ?

Answer (score 0):

This translate located in db. You can translate them by enabling "Translate Inline" via admin end: **System -> Developer -> Translate Inline** (for desire store). When you enabled them, you can add translate via site user end (click on the book at text). If you don't see the book - clean cache. After changed - clean cache.

Comment: Btw, do I have to take my website offline for customers? Because it's a live webshop :O

Comment: Yes. Your clients can change translated too